# simple animation from a given website

Tags: css, animation

I'm completely new to CSS Animations and I wanted to simulate the effect found on this site: http://pl.playstation.com/psn/ . In the middle of the screen (white background) there are some characters and in front of them there are some blue symbols (cross, circle, square) that go up and down quite smoothly. How to simulate same effect on an example div? I've looked into the code of their animation and found something like:

```
-webkit-animation-duration: 4000ms;
transition-delay: 1500ms;
-webkit-animation: infinite alternate ease-in-out;
-webkit-perspective: 1000;
transition: opacity 1000ms,transform 1000ms;
```

How to make elements move based on this? Do I have to make some transform: translate() and give some values and how to fire it automatically when somebody is on the page?

Comment: you can use `transform:translate(x, y)`

Comment: O.K. so I've created this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jauo1ayw/ and tried to use translate(Y) but don't know how to make it animate down and then again up and so on continuosly all the time like on the site provided above.

Comment: what's the effect you're looking for? You could outline it here? Or post an image example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use keyframes for this - just don't forget to include prefixing for cross browser compatibility!

The Idea behind keyframes is that you can animate items very quickly, using the keyframe syntax of:

```
@keyframes Floating {
  from {
    transform: translate(0, 0px);
  }
  65% {
    transform: translate(0, 15px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translate(0, -0px);
  }
}
```

which will translate it as you desire.

---

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/rkzZG/370/)

```css
.floating {
  float: left;
  -webkit-animation-name: Floatingx;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -moz-animation-name: Floating;
  -moz-animation-duration: 3s;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-name: Floating;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
@-webkit-keyframes Floatingx {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0px);
  }
  65% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 15px);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -0px);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes Floating {
  from {
    -moz-transform: translate(0, 0px);
  }
  65% {
    -moz-transform: translate(0, 15px);
  }
  to {
    -moz-transform: translate(0, -0px);
  }
}
@keyframes Floating {
  from {
    transform: translate(0, 0px);
  }
  65% {
    transform: translate(0, 15px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translate(0, -0px);
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/200" class="floating" />
```

Comment: @Shepherd: thank you. But could you do me one thing? Don't just copy and paste this - look into how it's working and if need be ask questions about *how* it works. :)